# Почему цикл Wordpress выводит только один пост?

Tags: wordpress, функции, циклы, while

Не могу понять, что не так делаю -

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'metka_blog'
            )
        )
    );

    $query_new = new WP_Query( $args );
    var_dump($query_new);
    if ( $query_new->have_posts() ) {
        while ($query_new->the_post());
        $query_new->the_post();
        ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="blog-card">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('sidebar-preview'); ?></a>
                                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    <?php 
    }

?>
```

Подскажите, где и что не так делаю? 
В переменной $query_new - 3 поста, которые отображаются с помощью var_dump

Но если хочу их вывести в произвольном цикле - то выводит только 1 Пост? почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в коде:

```
while ($query_new->have_posts());
```

Comment: Всё равно один пост... ((

Comment: в аргументы WP_Query добавь posts_per_page => -1

Comment: Добавил... но результат не изменился( Вот вроде бы всё правильно, но где ошибка понять не могу...